# Is SIGCHLD dispatched on SIGTERM?

Tags: linux, signals

The [Wikipedia page for SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) says:

> The SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent of a child process when it
>   exits, **is interrupted**, or resumes after being interrupted.

Does that mean that when the parent process sends any signal (such as `SIGTERM`) to the child process, it will in turn receive a `SIGCHLD` back from the child?

Or do I misinterpret *interrupt* (I assume it to mean *any signal received*), in this case, which signals are concerned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A SIGCHLD is delivered to the parent in these cases:

- The child process exits.
- The child process is stopped by a SIGSTOP, SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN or  SIGTTOU signal
- The child process is resumed by a SIGCONT signal

I would presume the SIGSTOP/SIGCONT is what wikipedia means by "interrupted".

The default handler for SIGTERM is to terminate the process. So if the parent sends SIGTERM to the child process which terminates that child, then yes - the parent will receive a SIGCHLD.

If the child installs a signal handler that does not terminate it, there will be no SIGCHLD signal delivered to the parent.

Comment: Sorry, `SIGTERM` was a bad example. When I send `SIGTERM` to my child processes, they will catch the signal and perform some cleanup before exiting; only `SIGKILL` would terminate them immediately. Should I understand then that if `SIGTERM` is caught by the child, `SIGCHLD` is not sent to the parent?

Comment: @Benjamin When the child terminates, for _whatever_ reason, SIGCHLD is delivered to the parent.

Comment: I got that, I'm just trying to figure out what other reasons might trigger a `SIGCHLD`. The Wikipedia page says it's also dispatched when the process is *interrupted*: what does that mean?

Comment: Just saw your update above, that explains it all. `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` are the two other possible reasons for `SIGCHLD` to be dispatched. Thanks!